# Wordpress - how to add new CSS classes to a specific div on a specific archive page

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, foreach

I'm looking for how to target a specific div on a specific page and add multiple new css classes to that div.

I have a projects page with page ID 1690. (basically an archive but using Elementor loop grid) that displays all projects. Each project is within a div with the following css classes and data-id:
`<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-ee4ea21 e-con-boxed e-con" data-id="ee4ea21" data-element_type="container">`

For each project, I want to add all taxonomy terms that are associated with each post as css classes so that I can use css and javascript to filter the page based on the taxonomy terms.

I tried echoing javascript just to test adding a simple class to a specific div based on data-id but nothing happened:

```
function emoe_add_class_to_div() {
    if(is_page( 1690 )  ) {
        echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
            var ediv = document.querySelector('[data-id=\"ee4ea21\"]');
            ediv.classList.add(\"trish\");

        });</script>";
    }
}

add_action ('wp' ,'emoe_add_class_to_div' );
```

I found the below code which adds taxonomy terms as css classes to the body tag - seems like what I need except I need to put the classes in a specific div on the page - which I just don't know how to target:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class' );
 // Add taxonomy terms name to body class
function themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class( $classes ){
    if( is_singular() ) {
        global $post;
        $taxonomy_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'your_taxonomy'); // change to your taxonomy
        if ( $taxonomy_terms ) {
            foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term ) {
            $classes[] = 'tax_' . $taxonomy_term->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Thanks for any insights you can share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first block of code try to use "wp_footer" instead of "wp". The "wp" hook will trigger the code to run before the element has loaded therefore, it will not be able to find it. Also make sure that jQuery is enabled (I'm guessing it already is).

So the code should look like this:

```
function emoe_add_class_to_div() {
    if(is_page( 1690 )  ) {
        echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){
            var ediv = document.querySelector('[data-id=\"ee4ea21\"]');
            ediv.classList.add(\"trish\");

        });</script>";
    }
}

add_action ('wp_footer' ,'emoe_add_class_to_div' );
```

Comment: Thank you, SmamS! That worked. :) I very much appreciate it! ..... I'm wondering how I would use the second code box from my question along with this one to add each posts' taxonomy terms as the css class vs "trish"